# React Native flex and custom component layout issue

Tags: react-native

I've a simple React Native component:

```js
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It is used by this App:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

I expect the TestComponent and the yellow view to be displayed but using only required space and the blue view to fill up the remaining content.

The yellow and blue area is working as expected, but the TestComponent is not displayed. Why?

[image: iOS example]

See this demo: https://snack.expo.io/@dennismadsen/great-fudge

Answer (score 0):

The reason why '`TestComponent`' is not visible is because the parent flex value is zero. The flex will be covered together in yellow with zero.

You have to set flex values to see all colors and letters.

> red: 1 yellow : 1 blue : 8 === 1:1:8 === 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.8

```js
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 8, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

You can use two things if you want to make the text equal to the height of the second view. You can use `flexBasis` or `height`

'`flexBasis`' and '`height`' do the same thing.

OR

You can also use `flexShrink`.

```js
// use `flexBasis` or `height`
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red',flexBasis: 20 }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green',height: 20 }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
 use `flexShrink`.
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red',flexBasis: 20 }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green',flexShrink:0 }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

Remove Flex value

```js
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
          <Text>222222222222222222</Text>
          <Text>111111111111111111</Text>
          <Text>535555555555</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
....
      <View>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
```

**See Screen**

[image: df]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not know the height of the screen, and do not know the height of the content inside the red and yellow containers. Wherefore I'm not able to find some flex combination that will always make the containers have the height of the content of red and green.

Comment: @dhrm You can remove flex value

Comment: @dhrm Look at my revised answer.

Comment: @dhrm If my answer was helpful, would you please select my answer?

Answer (score 0):

just don't use flex:0 
use flex:1 in component that you want to fill the remain screen
the 2 others don't write any flex

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Does not seem to work: https://snack.expo.io/rkng7WNIB. Works fine on their web-view, but when running on my own device the red container is not shown.

Comment: because <TestComponent /> is empty it should contain any thing

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `flex: 0` from your JSX and it will work.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <TestComponent />
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Reason:
When you want only 1 component to cover the rest area then you just need to give the element `flex: 1` and leave others as is, so that they can only take the required space. When you explicitly assign `flex: 0` then it won't even take the required space.

FYI, I already tried this in the demo link you have shared.

EDITED:

```js
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Test</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

OR

```js
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to get it working here: https://snack.expo.io/rkng7WNIB. Works fine on their web-view, but when running on my own device the red container is not shown.

Comment: Okay give me sometime, let me try on device

Comment: So the TestComponent itself cannot use flex for this to work?

Comment: Since the parent is not having `flex` property, the child can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just remove `flex:1` from `<Testcomponent/>` then you test component take size according to its content.

Please check this demo link

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/new-component

Working demo image

[image]